# Constantly Update Current Time Display On A Windows Form?

Tags: .net, time, real-time-updates

I have a windows form where I want the time to constantly be updated. Right now it will take the current time from when the program was started.

For example, if I started the program at 5:30:29 PM that is what it will show the whole time the program runs.I need it to constantly be updated as the seconds tick by. So, If I started the program at 5:30:29 PM and ran it for exactly 5 minutes, the time displayed then should be 4:35:29 PM.

i want to do this in .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Timer` control and set the time interval to 1 second i.e. `1000` and for each Timer tick, update the current time. For example here is the C# solution, assume the timer `timer1` and lets say you want to show the time at the label `dateTimeLbl.Text` then here is the `timer1_tick` event:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimeLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) control to your Form.

Set the `Interval` to be `500`

This is a value in milliseconds so it ensures that it fires twice a second. If you use 1000 for one second your time could be (at worst case) nearly a second out because you don't know when in the second it will fire.

Set the `Enabled` property to `True`

Then update your display every time the timer ticks

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
End Sub
```